# Replace/remove file extensions in native search

Tags: replace, squarespace

I have a client that's looking to hide/remove the .jpeg tags that show up while searching their website (Squarespace, yeah).

In my head, something like this should work...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
const attrObserver = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach((mu) => {
    if (mu.type !== "attributes" && mu.attributeName !== "class") return;
    trimEXT();
  });
});

const ELS_test = document.querySelectorAll(".search-results");
ELS_test.forEach((el) => attrObserver.observe(el, { attributes: true }));

function trimEXT() {
  $(".search-results img").ready(function () {
    $(".sqs-search-page .sqs-title").html(function () {
      return $(this).html().replace(".jpg", " ").replace(".png", " ").replace(".jpeg", " ");
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  trimEXT();
});
</script>
```

...but it doesn't. Any thoughts on what i'm missing?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the HTML looks like so we can replicate your findings?